# CPT Menu is being hidden when I click and open the CPT page

Tags: php, wordpress, submenu

I am working on a new WordPress plugin. I have added a submenu from CPT [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHYmv.png)

But when I click and open that submenu page, the menu is being hidden
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdjFv.png)

I want to show the menu when I am on " Event" post type page. Would like to have suggestions from experts.
Thanks,
Moon